# use limit and where in php

Tags: php, selection, limit

I wrote this piece of code in PHP.

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM app WHERE" . $_REQUEST['filter']  . " ORDER BY " . $_REQUEST['sort']);

$output = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $record = array();
    $record['app_id'] = $row['app_id'];
    $record['app_name'] = $row['app_name'];

    $output[] = $record;
}
```

I want to use LIMIT as well.

When i usen LIMIT at `.....  " ORDER BY " . $_REQUEST['sort'] "LIMIT 3");`
it gives me this error:
filter =1=1
sort = 1=1

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ....service.php on line 80
```

How can I do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You are open to SQL injections with this code. If `$_REQUEST['filter']` is a string this query is invalid as well. Have you tried adding `limit` to your query? You also missed concatenation here,  `$_REQUEST['filter'] " ORDER BY "` So I suspect you aren't using error reporting/checking logs.

Comment: Yes i've used LIMIT at the end of this code but it didn't work

Comment: This is not a PHP question, you could read more about mysql queries itself: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: Did you read my whole comment? You should include your attempt to use limit.

Comment: @Markomafs he does have PHP errors in this code.

Comment: probably because of  $_REQUEST['filter']. 
in a where statement you should use field and values

Comment: you should more about into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php/60496#60496

Comment: OP should check error logs/enable reporting. Should be getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '" ORDER BY "' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)` so there is no mysql usage yet..

Comment: I've edited my post with the error it gave

Comment: Show your working code, the non working code, and what values are being passed in. I don't see how `$_REQUEST['filter']` is going to work unless you are passing raw SQL to this page...(bad idea).

Comment: I gave 1=1 to filter and 1=1 to sort

Answer (score 1):

Append it to the query like this:

```
mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM app WHERE" . $_REQUEST['filter'] " ORDER BY " . $_REQUEST['sort'] . " LIMIT 1,1");
```